# How to shuffle data at each epoch using tf.data API in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am getting my hands dirty using TensorFlow 2.0 to train my model. The new iteration feature in `tf.data` API is pretty awesome. However, when I was executing the following codes, I found that, unlike the iteration features in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`, it did not shuffle data automatically at each epoch. How do I achieve that using TF2.0?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
def sample_data():
    ...

data = sample_data()

NUM_EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 128

# Subsample the data
mask = range(int(data.shape[0]*0.8), data.shape[0])
data_val = data[mask]
mask = range(int(data.shape[0]*0.8))
data_train = data[mask]

train_dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_train).\
                                 shuffle(buffer_size=10000).\
                                repeat(1).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_val).\
                                 batch(BATCH_SIZE)


loss_metric = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)

@tf.function
def train_step(inputs):
    ...

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    # Reset the metrics
    loss_metric.reset_states()
    for inputs in train_dset:
        train_step(inputs)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch needs to be reshuffled:

```
train_dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_train).\
                                repeat(1).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

train_dset = train_dset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)
```